# connect() error: operation not permitted

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I am working through examples in UNIX Network Programming and I've adapted "daytimeclientcli.c" into this code here which is linux specific (those examples use BSD).  I've run the program against time servers on [here](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi). Regardless of the server i get `connect error: Operation not permitted` which is the return value from the call to connect().  I've searched around but I can't find anything related to this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFER 80
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int sockfd;
  int n;
  char buf[BUFFER+1];
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  /* need a pointer to socketaddr for call to connect() */
  struct sockaddr* ptr;

  if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "socket error\n");
    return 2;
  }

  memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(13);

  if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr) <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "inet_pton error for %s\n", argv[1]);
    return 3;
  }

  ptr = (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr;
  if (err = connect(sockfd, ptr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "connect error: %s\n", strerror(err));
    return 4;
  }

  /* read from socket */
  while ( (n = read(sockfd, buf, BUFFER)) > 0);

  if (n < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "read error: %d\n", n);
    return 5;
  } else {
    /* null-terminate the buffer */
    buf[n] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", buf);
 }

  if (n < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "read error");
    return 5;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need root permissions.

Comment: Shouldn't need root perms, but do you have firewall rules that block the port outgoing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The connect() call is failing because servaddr has not been initialized correctly.  In the call to inet_pton(), try changing "&serv_addr" to "&serv_addr.sin_addr".

Comment: well, i don't get the connect() error anymore, but I'm not getting any response from the time servers, lol. I had this same issue earlier, though. I think they are rather unreliable.