# enable to list udp port in xcode 9 for an ios app by GCDAsyncUdpSocket

Tags: ios, xcode, gcdasyncudpsocket

I am trying to listen to a udp port from my ios app by

> GCDAsyncUdpSocket

and keep getting this error:

```
UDP connection error on port 60834 becuase Operation not permitted
```

from

```
GCDAsyncUdpSocket
```

it looks like I need to disable sandbox on my app and I tried to do it via

> com.apple.security.app-sandbox
>   in plist but not luck yet.

thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you checked this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489313/connect-error-operation-not-permitted

Comment: thanks for your reply. I use CocoaAsyncSocket pod to do so and getting that error

Comment: Can you please add some code in your question.

Comment: Thanks much for you time. I've fixed as my connection class was belong two targets in xcode and init two times.